Issue with Login Screen Not Appearing on Ubuntu 24.04?
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my system, but I'm encountering a problem where the login screen does not appear. Instead, the system shows the following error during boot:
nvrm: the Nvidia GeForce 820m GPU installed on this system is supported through the Nvidia 390.xx legacy drivers. 
Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information. 
The 565.57.01 Nvidia driver will ignore this GPU. Continue probe...

Additionally:
Following commands does not show any output.
ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu list
ubuntu-drivers list-oem


As stated; you will need to install Nvidia 390.xx legacy drivers (apparently a manual download and install) replacing the currently installed 565.57.01-version. Your old GPU is not supported by the latest driver.
To visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html  you need a text mode browser e.g. links or lynx - these can be installed from the recovery console.
Now these browsers take some getting used to; so I'll spare you the details.

First reboot into the recovery console;
Reboot, and hit ESC once while the BIOS/UEFI texts get displayed.
This should make the grub boot menu appear.
In there you have an "advanced" option, select it with the cursor keys, then hit Enter.
A new menu appears and shows at least one "recovery" option, select it and hit Enter.
In the recovery mode menu, select fsck, networking and root prompt options in that order.
The last leaves you at a intermediate prompt, hit Enter once more.

You're now the root user at a Bash prompt.
type
wget https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.157/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run
... on a single line, and hit enter
This should download NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run into the current dir, so be shown as you type ls -l and hit Enter.
Now you need to purge all currently installed nvidia-packages, this can be done by repeatedly do;
dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii.*nvidia'
and then do
apt purge packagename
for each of the listed names in column two.
Depending on the order you do this in, some may get purged together with others due to dependencies.
So you might not need to manually purge all of them.
If you begin with nvidia-driver... you might get very lucky ;-)
When dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii.*nvidia' no longer list any packages, you will then have to do:
bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run
... to launch the installation of that driver.
As that has been succesfully done,
type reboot and hit Enter.
Note: bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run --help | less is likely to print a busload of information about the driver and the options it has; it might be a way forward in case of issues.
A last note: The *.RUN drivers has HAD a tendency to get "pushed aside" by updates to kernel and/or windowing systems (X, Wayland). So beware that you might need to get back into the recovery console after such updates, and there just do
bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run --uninstall
and then immediately after;
bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run again.
... and a final reboot to restart.
All this is from memory, so might contain something I missed
